# Soap NTLM Authorization

Tags: web-services, http, authorization, ntlm

I'm trying to access a webservice that it's protected with NTLM Authorization. Usually, for a normal webservice protected with basic HTTP Auth I can authenticate using the "Authorization" header in the following way:

Authorization : "BASIC OASDmkAsofnASncvosNoaisdf"

where the string after the "BASIC" its the "username:password" encoded in base64.

My question is, it is possible to do something similar for NTLM?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 1):

What client are you using for the webservice? IF you are using the microsoft webservices client (not WFC) then you can get the underlying HttpWebRequest and set the credentials on it.

I am not sure how to do this on WCF.

I strongly suggest that you use microsoft web service clients for this. NTLM is a multi-leg challenge response protocol, and it is not easy to implement it in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using salesforce (a cloud computing platform) so i'm limited to plain HTTP headers :(

Comment: NTLM is "plain http headers" but as feroze mentions, each NTLM authentication consists of multiple roundtrips, and at each roundtrip you have to examine the prior response and calculate a new request header (which is NOT trivial) to send on the subsequent request.